# Finding probability of Gaussian random variable with range

Tags: matlab, random, probability, probability-density

I am a beginner in MATLAB trying to use it to help me understand random signals, I was doing some Normal probability density function calculations until i came across this problem :

Write a MATLAB program to calculate the probability `Pr(x1 ≤ X ≤ x2)`
if X is a Gaussian random variable for an arbitrary `x1` and `x2`.

Note that you will have to specify the `mean` and `variance` of the Gaussian random
variable.

I usually use the built in `normpdf` function of course selecting my mean and variance, but for this one since it has a range am not sure what I can do to find the answer

```
 Y = normpdf(X,mu,sigma)
```

Comment: "...selecting my mean and variance" Note that [`normpdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html) uses the input argument `sigma` as standard deviation, not variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you recall from probability theory, you know that the [Cumulative Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) sums up probabilities from `-infinity` up until a certain point `x`.  Specifically, the CDF `F(x)` for a probability distribution `P` with random variable `X` evaluated at a certain point `x` is defined as:

[image]

Note that I am assuming that we are dealing with the discrete case.  Also, let's call this a **left-tail** sum, because it sums all of the probabilities from the left of the distribution up until the point `x`. Consequently, this defines the **area** underneath the curve up until point `x`.

Now, what your question is asking is to find the probability between a certain range `x1 <= x <= x2`, not just with using a left-tail sum (`<= x`).  Now, if `x1 <= x2`, this means that total area where the end point is `x2`, or the probability of all events up to and including `x2`, is also **part** of the area defined by the end point defined at `x1`.  Because you want the probability between a certain range, you need to accumulate all events that happen between `x1` and `x2`, and so you want the area under the PDF curve that is in between this range.  Also, you want to have the area that is **greater** than `x1` and less than `x2`.

Here's a pictorial example:

[image]
<sup>[Source: ReliaWiki](http://reliawiki.com/index.php/Appendix_A:_Brief_Statistical_Background)</sup>

The top figure is the PDF of a Gaussian distribution function, while the bottom figure denotes the CDF of a Gaussian distribution.  You see that if `x1 <= x2`, the area defined by the point at `x1` is **also** captured by the point at `x2`.  Here's a better graph:

[image]
<sup>[Source: Introduction to Statistics](https://work.thaslwanter.at/Stats/html/statsDistributions.html)</sup>

Here the CDF is continuous instead of discrete, but the result is still the same.  If you want the area **in between** two intervals and ultimately the probability in between the two ranges, you need to take the CDF value at `x2` and **subtract** the CDF value at `x1`.  You want the **remaining** area, and so you just need to **subtract** the CDF values and ultimately the left-tail areas, and so:

[image]

As such, to calculate the CDF of the Gaussian distribution use [`normcdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) and specify the mean and standard deviation of your Gaussian distribution.  Therefore, you just need to do this:

```
y = normcdf(x2, mu, sigma) - normcdf(x1, mu, sigma);
```

`x1` and `x2` are the values of the interval that you want to calculate the sum of probabilities under.

Comment: This is simpler, I also tested it with my code and I got same results Yeeeh +1,

Comment: sorry for double posting, but how can i plot the the results, ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `erf`,

```
mu = 5;
sigma = 3;
x1 = 3;
x2 = 8;
p = .5*(erf((x2-mu)/sigma/2^.5) - erf((x1-mu)/sigma/2^.5));
```

`error function` is defined like this in MATLAB,

[image]

Comment: Actually `normcdf` uses `erf` under the hood, so you actually exposed what `normcdf` is actually doing :)  +1 for you too my friend.